# Write to socket directly and get TCP ZeroWindow

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, window

Just as you can see, I send a request to the specific socket every 10 seconds directly( to remain alive and be detected ), but it can only send twice. Using wireshark, I found that the third package I send has `TCP ZeroWindow` and it cannot send to the server. So does the following packages. Usually, the Window Size should remain at a normal level instead of decreasing all the time. What's wrong with the source code? Any help appreciated!

***Three packages I got:***

[image: The First Package]
[image: The Second Package]
[image: The Third Package]

***Source code: very simple***

```
public class pediy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://bbs.pediy.com");
        Socket socket = null;
        PrintWriter os = null;
        BufferedReader is = null;

        while(true) {

            socket = new Socket(url.getHost(), 80);
            os = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            String request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: bbs.pediy.com\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17 CoolNovo/2.0.6.12\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\nAccept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\nAccept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\n";
            try {
                while (true) {

                    os.println(request);
                    os.flush();

                    System.out.println("Finished");
                    Thread.sleep(1000*10);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error" + e);
            } finally {
                CloseAll(socket, os);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CloseAll(Socket socket, PrintWriter os) throws IOException {
        if(socket != null) socket.close();
        if(os != null) os.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simply means the other side of the TCP connection is not consuming (reading) the data you send, so TCP flow control kicks in to slow the sender down.

Comment: You mean that it's not wrong of my code but the server? But If I send the same HTTP request using chrome every 10 seconds, it will run well. Nothing wrong happends. Why?

Comment: You probably want to read server's response before submitting next request.

Comment: I have tried to read the server's response, and the response seems OK according to Wireshark, but the TCP Window is still Zero

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. You aren't sending valid HTTP. The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not just `\n`, and there needs to be a blank line after the headers.
2. You aren't reading the responses.

So the other end will be having some difficulty. You're lucky it hasn't closed the connection already.

Comment: I have changed `\n` to `\r\n` and add a stream to read data which is sent back to me, I have also catched the response in Wireshark, but the window size is still Zero. In fact, I don't care what the response is. What's more, because I want to make such an app for android, the response will cost some data flows that are unnecessary originally.

Comment: It doesn't matter in the least whether you care what the response is or not. You have to read it, otherwise the server will get into difficulties sending them. These data flows are not 'unnecessary'. They are a part of the HTTP protocol, which *you* aren't implementing correctly, and therefore *you* are getting into difficulties.

Comment: Thanks, what you said sounded reasonable. I added an variable: `BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));` and read the response in the while loop: `while(is.read() != 0);`. Also, I catched the response in Wireshark, but the TCP Window is still Zero, where in the code may be the point?